# Testing for Unit Roots with Quadratic Trends in Stata

Tags: time-series, unit-root, quadratic-form

I understand that Dickey-Fuller test could test for a unit root with drift and deterministic time trend.
$$
\nabla y_t = a_0+a_1t+\delta y_{t-1}+u_t \
$$

What are the tests for unit root with **quadratic trends**? In particular, how can I test it in Stata? 
$$
\nabla y_t = a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2+\delta y_{t-1}+u_t \
$$